# set value to master page controls inside content page in asp .net mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am using this code inside content page to change label value of Master page. But this is not working. I'm doing this in MVC 2 aspx View.

```
<%
        Label lbl = this.Master.FindControl("cov_year") as Label;
        lbl.Text = "Show val";

     %>
```

Comment: This is webforms code, not MVC

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is webform code, so it is not working in MVC view. So, I used jquery to find and set value.

```
<script>
   var txt = "<%= titleformat%>";
   $("#cov_year").text(txt);
</script>
```